# Setting Fish Shell as default shell, prevents me from accessing commands

Tags: shell, macos, fish

I used the following to set my default shell

```
chsh -s `which fish`
```

Which works great, but many commands such as brew and npm no longer works. Previously, accessing fish shell from zsh shell still allows me to access those commands.

How do I enable Fish shell to access the commands or at least add the commands.

Comment: Didn't I see this question earlier today?

Comment: @glennjackman yes, but I was told I should ask the question here. And I wanted to see if there are other potential solutions regarding my issue

Comment: You probably don't have your `PATH` set up correctly. Check what the value is in your previous shell with `echo "$PATH"` (or in zsh with every path on one line: `for p in $path; echo $p`) and adding the missing ones to fish. Sometimes these programs set up things in `/etc/profile.d` or whatnot for Bourne-like shells, but that won't work for fish so you'll need to do it manually.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I see, thank you. That helped